# Strange XAML Parse behaviour when set Text and add Interaction.Triggers. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception, xamlreader

I set the **Text** property of the **Textbox** control, and also i add an Interaction.Trigger to it. 
An exception is thrown When I try to parse the this XAML using `XamlReader.Parse()`:

The xaml which i have is:

```
<Grid xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"        
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Name="TopPanel" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />        
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>       
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
    <TextBox Name="TextBox_8241" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" xml:space="preserve" 
            Text="{Binding ppp, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">    
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">        
                    <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding TextBox_8241_MouseEnterCommand}" />      
                </i:EventTrigger>    
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>  
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

The exception message is:
{"''Text' property has already been set on 'TextBox'.' Line number '1' and line position 'X'."}

**line position** points to the closing tag of TextBox **`</TextBox>`**

If I don't set any Interaction.Triggers it parses OK, but at least one Interaction.Triggers set, it throws the exception...

Can anyone give me some light on this please?

Comment: this Grid is in some resources or is directly a part of Control?

Comment: @DJ the Grid is a part of control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the `xml:space="preserve"` line in your TextBox declaration. If you'll drop it, it will parse as expected.

Comment: Thank you Adi Lester. It is right! `xml:space="preserve"` is the problem.